# How to create a scatter plot or heatmap of spearman's correlation

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, correlation

I have two dataframes 'A' and 'B' each of them is having 1000 values(some values are missing from each column).

Dataframe 'A'

```
([-1.73731693e-03, -5.11060266e-02,  8.46153465e-02,  1.48671467e-03,
    1.52286786e-01,  8.26033395e-02,  1.18621477e-01, -6.81430566e-02,
    5.11196597e-02,  2.25723347e-02, -2.98125029e-02, -9.61589832e-02,
   -1.61495353e-03,  3.72062420e-02,  1.66557311e-02,  2.39392450e-01,
   -3.91891332e-02,  3.94344811e-02,  4.10956733e-02,  6.69258037e-02,
    7.92391216e-02,  2.59883593e+00,  1.54048404e+00, -4.92893250e-01,
   -2.91309155e-01, -8.63923310e-01, -8.51987780e-01,  4.60905145e-01,
    2.76583773e-01,  1.68323381e+00,  1.82011391e+00,  3.68951641e-01,
   -1.35627096e+00, -1.24374617e+00, -1.97728773e+00,  2.70233476e+00,
   -5.60139584e-01, -8.50132695e-01,  1.85987594e+00, -2.89995402e+00,
    2.05908855e+00, -2.36161146e-01, -6.62032149e-01, -3.46654905e-01,
    1.60181172e+00,  1.65443393e+00, -3.77934113e-03, -7.94313157e-01,
    5.20531845e-03, -5.24688509e-01, -1.57952723e+00,  3.14415761e-01,
   -9.32905832e-01, -1.34278662e-01, -1.84121185e+00, -1.67941178e-01,
   -1.21144093e+00,  3.76283451e-01,  5.61453284e-01, -6.26859439e-01,
   -4.66613293e-02,  2.56535385e-01, -5.86989954e-01, -4.21848822e-01,
    5.21841502e-01,  5.76096822e-01, -1.58315586e-01, -3.31595062e-02,
   -5.72139189e-01,  7.27998737e-01,  1.54143678e+00,  2.58551028e+00,
    1.11951220e+00,  2.08231826e+00,  8.48119597e-01,  3.91317082e-01,
    1.45425737e+00, -5.08802476e-01, -9.04742166e-01, -4.39964548e-02,
   -5.07664895e-01,  1.34800131e-01,  6.60639468e-01, -7.81770841e-02,
    1.77803055e-01, -5.25474907e-01,  1.56286558e+00,  1.37397348e+00,
    9.35845142e-01, -8.29997405e-01, -1.12959459e+00, -7.34076036e-01,
   -1.34298352e+00, -1.55242566e+00, -3.48126090e-01,  9.46175316e-01,
    1.04627046e+00,  2.78090673e-01,  5.24197520e-01, -7.31359265e-01,
    9.81771972e-01, -7.06560821e-01,  9.87914170e-01,  4.21145043e-01,
    7.99874801e-01, -3.61598953e-01, -6.91521208e-02, -3.02639311e-01,
    1.22688070e-02, -1.28362301e-01,  1.55251598e+00,  1.50264374e+00,
   -1.50725278e+00, -1.15365780e-01, -9.54988005e-01, -8.96627259e-01,
   -2.83129466e-01, -1.30206622e+00, -8.17198805e-01,  1.10860713e+00,
   -9.80216468e-01, -8.91534692e-01, -8.34263124e-01, -7.16062684e-01,
    9.43266610e-01, -6.39953720e-01,  2.20295404e-01,  6.53124338e-01,
    1.12831707e+00,  7.95192837e-01,  1.06274424e+00, -9.84363663e-01,
   -1.86648718e+00,  2.47560957e-01, -1.54991644e-01, -1.06641038e-01,
   -2.08836784e-03,  6.62447504e-01, -1.34260765e-01,  2.98202604e-01,
   -2.19112992e-01, -4.66701070e-01, -4.29040735e-02,  2.77548893e-01,
   -6.48395632e-02,  4.43922718e-01, -1.06670096e+00,  7.60389677e-01,
   -3.50944675e-01, -2.68452398e-01,  1.65183406e-01, -3.35291595e-01,
    8.29848518e-01,  5.20341409e-01,  8.95388863e-01,  2.10437855e-01,
    2.35693685e+00, -1.30064957e+00,  5.94602557e-02, -2.14385684e-02,
   -1.01823776e+00,  8.10292523e-01, -1.22324503e+00,  3.37151269e-01,
    6.34668773e-01, -6.14841220e-01, -3.06480016e-01, -8.71147997e-01,
   -2.38711565e-01, -3.71304349e-01, -5.21931353e-01, -7.25105848e-01,
    9.55749034e-01, -5.03756385e-01,  1.11945956e+00, -1.13072038e+00,
    1.46584643e+00, -1.03178731e+00,  1.49044585e+00,  4.29069135e-01,
    5.71108660e-01, -8.24272706e-01,  3.75994251e-01,  1.18141844e+00,
   -1.22185847e-01, -1.73339604e-03, -1.89326424e-01, -1.83774529e-02,
    1.63951866e-01,  2.68499548e-01,  4.42841678e-01, -5.51856731e-02,
   -2.09071328e-01, -1.80936048e-01, -1.32749060e-01, -1.37133946e-01,
    3.04451064e-01, -2.60560303e-02,  1.64786954e-01,  1.32592907e-01,
   -1.46235968e+00, -7.26806017e-01, -3.67486773e-01,  3.71101544e-01,
    8.83259501e-01, -7.15065260e-02,  1.66389135e+00, -1.78108597e+00,
   -1.26130490e+00, -2.24665654e-01, -8.12489764e-01,  5.74641618e-01,
   -4.67201906e-01, -1.12587866e+00,  7.75153678e-01,  5.72844798e-01,
   -1.26508809e+00,  8.06000266e-01, -6.82706612e-01,  1.50495168e+00,
    8.52438532e-01,  9.43195172e-01, -4.40088490e-02, -2.45587111e-01,
   -9.86037547e-01, -1.11312353e+00,  9.32310853e-01, -1.04108755e+00,
    4.26250651e-01,  1.70686581e-01, -2.64108584e-01,  8.06651732e-02,
    5.71204776e-01,  1.46614492e-01,  1.18698807e-01,  3.55246874e-04,
    6.77137159e-01,  1.15635393e-01,  1.34337204e-01,  3.27307728e-01,
   -2.05416923e-01,  4.18027455e-01,  9.88345937e-02,  2.18627719e-01,
   -5.18426174e-02, -1.17021957e-01,  1.70474550e-01,  4.82736350e-02,
    3.21336545e-01, -1.45544581e-01, -1.20319001e-01,  2.03828814e-01,
   -3.08498184e-02, -1.40565005e+00, -1.43214088e-01,  4.97504769e-01,
    1.56273785e-01,  2.75011645e-01, -4.60341398e-03,  1.43803337e+00,
    1.39331909e-01,  2.06784989e-01, -5.12059356e-01, -1.17023126e+00,
   -5.96174413e-01, -1.22451379e+00,  1.96344831e-01,  2.14817355e-01,
    1.24091029e-01,  5.14485621e-01, -6.03650270e-01, -1.65868324e+00,
   -8.21932382e-01, -7.13710026e-01, -8.08813887e-01, -8.04744593e-01,
   -1.06858314e-01, -4.50248193e-02, -2.20419270e-01,  8.09215220e-02,
    1.35851711e+00, -1.14235665e+00, -6.68174295e-02, -6.01281650e-01,
    2.34869773e-01,  3.67129075e-01, -1.34835335e+00,  7.52430154e-01,
    1.37352587e+00, -1.02421527e+00, -2.07610263e-02, -3.39083658e-02,
   -5.75996009e-02, -2.31073554e-02,  4.61795647e-02, -4.59340619e-01,
   -3.62781811e-01,  4.54813190e-02,  6.04157090e-02, -1.87268083e-01,
    1.70276057e-01, -8.61843513e-02, -1.27476047e+00,  1.30585731e+00,
   -6.46389245e-01, -1.40635401e-01, -1.77942738e+00, -1.41113903e-01,
    1.56715807e-01, -1.67712695e-01,  1.86451110e-01, -6.01158881e-02,
    4.64978376e-01,  5.13440781e-01,  6.19532336e-01,  2.54267587e-01,
   -2.78759433e-01, -3.88565967e-01,  3.87152834e-02,  1.06240041e+00,
    2.09454855e-01,  9.64690667e-03,  8.95837369e-02, -3.96816092e-01,
   -3.41660062e-01,  6.29889334e-01, -8.67980022e-03,  7.84849030e-01,
   -4.85106947e-01, -7.31377792e-01, -8.87659450e-01,  7.61389541e-01,
    9.76497314e-01, -1.06744789e+00,  1.47065840e+00,  6.25211618e-01,
    7.25988559e-01,  4.19787342e-01,  1.92491575e-01,  1.13681147e+00,
   -1.41299616e-01,  1.88563224e+00,  1.20414116e+00,  8.84760070e-02,
   -5.82623462e-01, -6.35685252e-01,  9.42374369e-01, -2.68795041e+00,
    1.55265515e-01,  1.11831120e+00,  1.42496225e+00, -2.49172328e+00,
   -2.96253872e+00, -1.27634582e+00,  8.64353099e-01,  1.75738299e+00,
   -1.08871311e+00, -9.71165087e-01,  7.15048842e-01, -2.17295734e-01,
   -9.51989200e-01, -2.18546988e-01,  9.17042794e-01,  8.62052366e-01,
   -1.85594903e-01,  4.56294789e-01, -6.85416684e-01, -2.80209189e-01,
   -5.46608487e-01,  1.08818926e+00, -7.21033879e-01, -6.71183475e-01,
   -6.36051999e-01, -4.59980192e-01, -5.05580110e-01, -3.78244959e-01,
   -7.24025921e-01, -2.08545177e-01,  4.57899036e-02,  4.40788256e-02,
   -2.37824313e-01,  1.52266134e+00,  8.17944390e-03,  1.10203927e+00,
    9.86476664e-01, -5.18193891e-01, -3.20302684e-01, -3.62147726e-01,
    8.09107079e-02, -2.23162278e+00,  1.08676773e+00,  5.61964453e-01,
    1.27519559e-01,  9.24886749e-01, -4.75508805e-01, -5.42765960e-01,
   -1.00917988e+00, -1.38181867e+00, -1.32190961e+00,  1.22737946e+00,
    3.60475117e-01,  4.94411259e-01, -9.84878721e-01, -1.27991181e+00,
    7.05733451e-01,  6.05978064e-01,  7.24010257e-01,  7.31500866e-01,
   -2.10270319e+00, -1.44749054e+00, -4.62989149e-01,  1.88742227e+00,
    2.23502013e+00,  1.24196002e+00, -8.39133460e-02, -5.83997089e-01,
    7.63111106e-01,  3.59541173e-01,  1.69019230e+00,  3.16779306e-01,
    8.04994106e-01, -7.79848130e-01,  4.55373478e-01, -6.99628529e-01,
   -8.88776585e-01,  5.58784034e-01,  1.03796435e+00, -1.39833046e+00,
   -1.30889596e+00,  1.92064711e+00, -1.03993971e+00, -5.44703609e-01,
   -1.25879891e+00, -2.25683759e+00, -1.61033547e-01,  1.76603501e-01,
   -2.47327624e-02,  6.42444167e-02, -6.01551357e-01, -7.00803499e-01,
    1.03391796e-02, -1.65584150e-01, -6.05071619e-01, -3.43937387e-01,
   -2.21285625e-01, -1.86325091e-02, -9.79578217e-01, -1.73186370e-02,
   -2.30215061e-02,  9.63819799e-01,  2.14069445e+00, -2.99999601e-01,
   -1.06696731e+00,  1.38805597e-01, -1.36281099e+00, -1.71499344e+00,
   -2.44679986e-01,  5.14666974e-02,  4.18733154e-01,  1.59951320e+00,
    1.00618752e+00, -1.88645728e+00,  1.59363671e+00, -1.70729555e-01,
    9.42793430e-02, -7.23224009e-02,  6.02105534e-02,  5.52374283e-01,
    6.91499535e-02,  9.86658898e-02,  1.26584605e-01, -5.92396665e-02,
    2.90992852e-01, -5.76585947e-01,  6.72979673e-02,  7.38910628e-01,
   -8.75090268e-02,  6.94842842e-02, -2.30246430e-01,  1.94134747e-01,
   -2.09682980e+00,  7.74844906e-01,  6.15444420e-01, -1.56931485e-01,
    1.66940287e+00, -1.45283370e+00,  1.37121988e-02,  1.07479283e+00,
    8.83275627e-01, -7.41385657e-01,  5.47602991e-01, -1.02874882e+00,
   -1.51215589e+00,  1.55364306e+00,  1.71320405e-01,  2.06341676e-01,
   -1.68945906e+00,  7.59196774e-01, -2.83121853e-01, -7.70003972e-01,
   -4.35559207e-01, -1.29156247e+00, -7.57105374e-01, -7.85287786e-01,
    1.31572406e-01,  1.20446876e+00, -1.46802375e+00, -5.35860581e-01,
    5.98595824e-01, -4.62785553e-01,  6.75677761e-02, -5.66531534e-01,
    1.09685209e+00,  8.24234006e-01,  1.13620680e+00,  3.96653080e-01,
    1.89639322e+00, -9.96802022e-01, -1.24232069e+00, -1.25410024e+00,
   -2.06379176e+00,  1.47885801e+00, -1.66257841e+00,  8.79827437e-01,
   -1.04440327e+00, -1.42881405e+00, -5.69974045e-01,  1.01359651e-01,
    4.86755601e-01, -3.35863751e-01,  2.64648983e-01,  1.27375046e-02,
   -6.16941256e-02,  4.08408937e-01,  7.55366537e-01, -7.27771779e-01,
    7.75935529e-01,  3.58925729e-01,  6.84118904e-01,  7.47932803e-01,
   -5.42091983e-01,  2.08484384e-01,  1.56950556e-01, -1.14533505e+00,
   -1.22366245e+00,  1.24506739e-01, -1.02935547e+00,  2.54296268e-01,
   -4.03847587e-01, -1.00212453e+00, -1.48661344e+00,  9.75954860e-01,
    9.38841010e-01, -1.23894642e+00, -9.78138112e-01, -1.04247682e+00,
   -1.03866562e+00,  1.26731592e+00, -3.67089461e-01, -8.48251235e-02,
   -1.82675815e+00,  6.06962041e-01, -2.33818172e-01, -4.57014619e-01,
    1.52576283e+00,  1.54494449e+00,  6.00789311e-01, -7.17249969e-01,
   -6.12826202e-01,  4.53766411e-01,  1.39275445e+00, -1.54383812e+00,
    1.54210845e+00,  2.69465492e-01, -2.30273047e+00,  1.73201080e+00,
   -2.46161686e+00, -8.25393337e-01,  4.33285105e-01,  7.14390347e-01,
    5.46413657e-01,  3.55625054e-01,  4.55356504e-01, -4.69216962e-01,
   -9.08073083e-01, -1.55192369e+00, -1.23692861e+00, -1.01703738e+00,
   -1.13617318e+00, -6.06261893e-01,  1.31444701e+00,  4.20469663e-01,
    1.25780763e-01, -3.17988182e-02,  8.14623566e-01,  8.66121880e-01,
   -7.69000333e-01, -1.67427496e-02, -7.96633360e-01, -3.49124840e-01,
   -2.07410767e-01, -1.09316367e-01, -2.86175298e-01,  4.21715381e-01,
    1.22897221e-01, -2.05947043e-01,  7.31217030e-01, -8.02955705e-01,
    8.88777313e-02,  2.07183542e-01, -4.79090236e-01, -6.23960583e-01,
   -4.50498790e-01, -1.08117179e-01, -2.59395547e-01, -7.48280208e-01,
    3.88011905e-01,  2.54908503e-01,  8.52262132e-01,  4.77972889e-01,
   -8.33500747e-02, -1.41622779e+00, -2.49822422e-01, -2.28753939e-01,
   -2.26889536e-01, -2.45202952e-01,  3.17116703e-01, -1.19760575e+00,
    7.04262050e-02, -5.31419343e-02, -7.31634189e-01, -4.17957184e-01,
    3.77288107e-01,  7.69283048e-01,  1.55929725e+00, -1.01963387e+00,
    9.07556960e-01, -4.98822527e-01,  1.02488029e+00,  5.58381436e-01,
   -2.14274914e+00, -6.94806179e-01, -1.11654335e+00, -1.11325319e+00,
   -1.10016520e+00,  5.18861155e-01, -1.04176598e+00, -8.66814672e-01,
    2.36604302e+00, -3.18431467e-01,  2.91334051e+00, -6.61828903e-02,
   -1.26603821e-02, -1.45414666e-01,  4.78580610e-02, -2.09898537e-03,
   -6.69714780e-02,  1.05549065e+00, -8.84106729e-02, -9.18073007e-04,
    1.25938385e+00, -8.14172470e-01, -2.59554042e-01, -6.95466246e-01,
    1.08730831e+00, -9.67021920e-01,  5.84575935e-02, -1.71321175e+00,
   -1.26317109e-01, -2.90733362e-01,  7.47312951e-03, -1.45607222e+00,
    4.60382102e-01,  1.61288034e+00, -5.28648252e-01,  1.66048408e-01,
    8.34903372e-01,  4.74884503e-01,  5.04686505e-01,  4.95510854e-01,
   -1.20924643e-01,  2.99423740e-01,  1.09738018e+00,  1.50838843e-01,
   -2.87229078e-01, -1.24761215e+00,  7.36582234e-01, -2.77173578e+00,
   -3.74992668e+00,  5.41312143e-01, -4.37583398e-01, -1.69064854e-02,
    1.84765431e+00,  5.73052756e-01, -1.06164050e+00,  5.07717049e-02,
    4.25819917e-02, -2.92715384e-01, -2.03200363e-01, -5.84490589e-01,
   -3.57083164e-01,  9.10876306e-01,  2.52143752e-01,  2.63129337e-02,
    3.83262339e-01,  7.74313729e-01, -3.60963951e-01, -7.70989956e-02,
    7.56541998e-01,  1.09766125e+00,  8.20902509e-01,  2.58690757e-01,
    1.25444572e+00,  5.71737922e-01,  2.55898541e-01, -8.80233282e-01,
    1.78192270e-01,  2.42501217e-01, -1.30266510e+00, -2.48044014e-02,
    1.07537714e-01,  1.67386472e-01, -1.11797061e-01, -6.35950485e-02,
    8.00025515e-02, -1.32397319e-01, -6.58003041e-03,  3.03937065e-01,
   -1.27135161e-01,  1.01363440e-01, -8.82766995e-01,  8.44379448e-01,
   -5.09627327e-01, -1.03326533e-01, -3.15431942e-01,  5.37076573e-01,
    3.26753114e+00,  4.15751153e-01,  2.56849348e-01,  5.14462581e-01,
   -2.61730161e-02, -3.28715744e-02,  1.88278800e-01, -1.19832919e+00,
   -1.19590287e+00, -1.11394334e+00,  2.17055714e+00,  7.96829829e-01,
   -1.85619100e+00, -1.07888882e+00, -2.30865383e-02, -2.40273840e-01,
    4.39953192e-01, -5.29613217e-01,  6.69906410e-01,  1.15145012e+00,
    6.06638031e-01,  5.99079947e-01,  9.16942482e-01, -9.66304057e-03,
    5.91654439e-02,  4.37388222e-01,  1.18295465e+00, -1.64263112e+00,
   -1.03293336e+00, -1.18222197e+00, -6.33519878e-02,  2.27962536e-01,
    1.66108232e+00, -1.23851592e+00, -1.43787196e+00,  8.87857019e-01,
   -1.19151817e+00, -1.47236056e+00,  3.50282869e-01,  1.06004408e+00,
   -4.26199859e-01,  4.37361363e-01, -2.50084772e-02,  8.67900174e-01,
    5.37760532e-01,  8.14530962e-02,  6.62491540e-01,  1.37045014e-01,
   -7.01697152e-01, -4.21657704e-01,  7.83331329e-01,  7.70034379e-01,
    1.28212695e+00,  2.53511223e+00, -3.24006440e-01, -3.41291501e-01,
   -2.49147123e-01,  1.70446849e-01, -1.37162583e-01, -4.81858038e-01,
   -4.86338762e-01,  6.85229336e-01, -1.55517356e-01,  1.83307879e-01,
   -1.49384229e-01,  1.56007957e-02,  2.40326236e-01,  1.07336933e+00,
   -3.99730396e-01, -3.33898955e-01,  3.40244317e-01, -4.92340248e-01,
   -4.95815316e-01,  6.22512483e-02,  5.08544685e-01, -2.83347226e-01,
   -3.08918714e-01,  1.08292681e+00, -5.29213035e-01, -2.23617454e-02,
    2.62202341e-01,  1.02718292e+00, -4.49869615e-01,  3.34969168e-01,
   -3.43212844e-01,  6.16483430e-01, -9.47779684e-01, -4.78857633e-01,
   -9.98923354e-01,  6.32191682e-01,  2.72973961e-01, -2.96008388e-01,
    2.30922383e-01,  2.06884014e-01,  5.21099867e-01,  4.16729600e-01,
   -8.26782099e-02, -5.95457632e-01, -2.10804413e-01, -2.93975286e-01,
    2.03009273e-01,  1.43593375e+00, -5.49739765e-01,  7.03821943e-01,
   -8.28059434e-01,  9.83503607e-01, -1.08534889e+00, -6.27821255e-01,
    4.03117722e-01, -2.03629129e-01, -3.95124233e-02,  3.21970160e-01,
   -2.71920636e-01, -5.10057329e-01, -1.04202621e-01,  3.20627596e-01,
    2.47291994e-01, -1.04118706e-01, -3.16545995e-01,  3.35604518e-01,
   -5.69433751e-03, -2.38370280e-01,  3.32991597e-01, -6.11308103e-02,
   -2.53167433e-01, -1.08142836e-01,  6.37938271e-01,  4.74190570e-01,
   -2.08524397e-01,  9.95434184e-01,  6.78813341e-01,  1.48137820e-01,
    3.66997494e-02,  1.12354066e-01,  1.33086253e+00,  6.58021086e-01,
    8.35274797e-01, -1.27346531e+00, -1.19618900e+00, -1.06490676e+00,
   -1.15966483e+00,  2.19041187e+00, -2.40703158e-01, -1.04679828e+00,
    5.26221976e-01,  9.57229098e-01, -3.17806974e-04,  5.25084392e-02,
    1.03682933e-01, -1.14126721e-01,  9.97109170e-02,  1.03757185e-01,
    4.10600042e-01,  5.78106727e-01,  1.01148051e+00, -4.79936067e-01,
   -1.32848972e+00, -2.20624284e-01, -1.42350771e+00, -1.17722544e-01,
   -4.78121525e-01, -7.67503366e-01,  1.88827881e-01, -5.96936872e-01,
    1.03021358e+00,  2.60795689e-02, -3.33047585e-03, -4.92126750e-01,
    1.11066769e+00,  1.01787072e+00, -1.20277626e+00,  7.53480929e-01,
   -1.13091340e+00, -4.33899313e-01, -1.50633595e+00, -1.39755762e+00,
    1.68206963e+00,  3.05696594e-02, -4.92375834e-01,  4.42329013e-01,
    2.13249223e+00, -1.16923258e+00, -7.43727428e-01,  9.63488691e-01,
   -1.40534085e+00,  1.30882281e+00, -1.22007716e+00,  7.24629619e-01,
    3.95142700e-01, -2.07336912e-01,  2.55075616e-01, -8.44328303e-02,
   -3.94616429e-01, -7.84743985e-02, -2.05229049e-01, -5.23357338e-01,
    3.31521045e-02, -1.46889669e+00,  4.00045935e-01,  1.27852950e-02,
   -2.18957838e+00, -9.22286699e-01, -1.00263590e-02, -2.15168189e-03,
   -9.58758007e-01,  1.40708729e-03,  4.08836699e-02, -3.10267180e-03,
   -1.97213536e-01, -1.57090203e-04, -6.56863610e-04, -3.41218036e-03,
    3.65899320e-02,  1.01258475e-02, -4.00850464e-03,  1.39965489e-03,
    1.87395867e+00, -2.50914219e-04, -1.36854426e-02, -5.59371636e-01,
    8.60638162e-01, -5.89030315e-02, -3.06438078e-01, -6.36052431e-02,
    6.98020295e-02,  1.09568657e-01, -4.95597777e-01, -1.45987919e-01,
    6.23584012e-01, -5.52485913e-01,  3.43299341e-01, -4.26641584e-01,
   -6.99084799e-02, -4.55572848e-01,  2.75544065e-01, -6.38720353e-01,
    3.68422013e-01,  4.06005693e-01, -2.99449896e-01,  9.50228459e-01,
    4.76344007e+00,  9.73504981e-02, -3.58437771e-01,  1.98629533e-02,
    9.93927115e-01,  5.36396410e-01,  5.36029608e-01,  1.42388869e+00,
    4.76638501e-01,  4.36781372e-01, -4.46066365e-01, -4.20019724e-01,
    5.00997260e-01,  5.30703691e-01,  1.74726375e-01,  2.35885059e-01,
   -3.33462461e-01, -8.84958758e-01,  1.70318874e-01, -5.73460407e-01,
   -5.17774883e-01, -3.75158795e-02,  1.68564324e+00,  4.88754154e-01])
```

Dataframe 'B'

```
[10000, 10000, 10000,  1000,  1000,  1000,  5000,  5000,  5000,
        1000,  5000,  5000, 10000,  5000,  1000,  1000,  5000,  1000,
       10000,  5000,  5000,  1000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000,
       10000, 10000,  1000,  1000,  1000,  1000,  1000,  1000,  1000,
        5000,  5000,  5000,  5000,  5000,  1000,  5000,  5000,  5000,
        5000, 10000, 10000,  1000, 10000,  1000, 10000, 10000, 10000,
        1000,  5000,  7500,  7500,  1000,  1000,  1000,  1000,  5000,
        5000,   500,   500,   500,   500,  7500,  7500,  5000,  5000,
       10000, 10000,  5000,  1000, 10000,  5000, 10000, 10000,  1000,
        5000,  5000,  5000,  1000,  5000, 10000,  5000, 10000, 10000,
        1000,  1000,  5000,  5000, 10000,  1000, 10000,  1000,  1000,
       10000, 10000,  1000,  5000, 10000,  5000, 10000,  1000,  1000,
        1000,  5000,  1000,  1000,  1000,  5000,  5000,  1000,  1000,
        5000,  5000,  1000,  5000, 10000,  1000,  1000,  5000, 10000,
        5000, 10000, 10000,  5000,  5000, 10000, 10000,  1000,  1000,
        5000, 10000, 10000, 10000,  1000,  1000,  1000,   300,   300,
        5000,  5000,  5000,  5000,  5000,  5000,  5000,  5000, 10000,
       10000,  1000,  1000,  1000,   300,  5000,  5000,  1000,  1000,
         300,   300,  5000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000,  1000,  1000,
        1000,  1000,   300,   300,  5000,  1000,  1000,  1000,   300,
         300,   300,  5000,  5000, 10000, 10000,  1000,  1000,   300,
         300,   300,   300, 10000, 10000,  1000,   300,   300,  5000,
        5000,  5000, 10000, 10000, 10000,  1000,  1000,  1000,   300,
        5000,  5000, 10000,  1000,   300,   300,  5000,  5000,  1000,
        1000,   300,   300,  5000, 10000,  1000,  1000,  1000,   300,
         300,  5000,  5000, 10000, 10000,  1000,  1000,  1000,   300,
        5000,  5000, 10000, 10000,  1000,   300,   300,  5000,  5000,
        1000,  1000,  1000,   300,   300,   300,   300,   300,   300,
        5000, 10000, 10000,  1000,  1000,  1000,  1000,  1000,   300,
         300,   300,   300, 10000,  1000,  1000,   300,   300,  5000,
       10000, 10000,  1000,  1000,  5000,  5000,  5000, 10000,  1000,
        1000,   300,   300,  5000,  5000,  1000,  1000,  1000,   300,
        5000,  5000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000,   300,   300,   300,
         300,  5000,  5000,  5000, 10000, 10000,  1000,   300,   300,
         300,  5000, 10000, 10000, 10000,  1000,  1000,  1000,  1000,
        5000,  1000,  1000,  1000,   300,   300,   300,   300,  5000,
        5000,  5000, 10000, 10000,  1000,   300,   300,  5000, 10000,
       10000,  5000,  5000,  5000,  5000,  5000,  5000,  5000,  5000,
        5000,  5000,  5000, 10000, 10000,  5000, 10000,  5000, 10000,
        1000,  1000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000,  5000,  1000,
       10000,  1000,  1000,  5000,  5000,  5000,  5000,  5000,   500,
         500,  7500,  1000,  5000,  1000,  5000,  1000,  5000,  5000,
        5000,  5000, 10000,  1000, 10000, 10000, 10000,  1000,  5000,
        5000,  1000,  5000, 10000,  1000,  5000,  5000,  5000, 10000,
        5000, 10000,  5000,  1000,  5000, 10000,  1000,  5000,  5000,
        5000,  1000,   210,   226,   442,  3511,  3511,  3511,  2310,
        1619,  2404,  1768,   837,  2241,  2382,  3774,  4432,   973,
         580,  1501,  2369,   473,  4626,  4635,   439,  1620,   850,
        1620,  1107,  2310,   390,  1982,  1587,  1497,  1588,   730,
        1619,  6546,  1000,  1000, 10000, 10000,  1000, 10000,  1000,
        1000, 10000, 10000,  1000,  5000,  5000,  5000, 10000,  1000,
       10000, 10000,  1000,  5000, 10000, 10000,  5000,  5000, 10000,
        5000, 10000, 10000,  5000,  5000,  5000, 10000,  1000,  5000,
        5000,  1000, 10000, 10000, 10000,  5000,  5000,  5000,  1000,
        5000,  5000,  1000, 10000, 10000,  1000,  1000, 10000,  1000,
        1000,  1000,  5000, 10000, 10000,  1000,  5000,  1000,  5000,
        5000, 10000, 10000, 10000,  5000,  5000,  1000,  1000, 10000,
        1000,  1000,  5000, 10000,  5000,  1000,  5000,  1000, 10000,
        5000, 10000,  1000,  5000,  5000, 10000, 10000,  1000,  5000,
       10000,  1000, 10000, 10000,  5000,  5000, 10000, 10000,  1000,
        5000, 10000,  1000,  1000,  5000,  5000,  5000,  5000, 10000,
       10000, 10000,  1000,  5000,  1000,  5000, 10000,  1000, 10000,
       10000,  5000,  1000,  5000,  1000,  1000, 10000,  1000,  5000,
        1000, 10000, 10000, 10000,  1000,  5000, 10000, 10000,  5000,
        5000, 10000,  1000,  5000,  1000,  1000, 10000, 10000,  1000,
       10000, 10000,  1000,  1000,  1000,  5000,  1000,  5000, 10000,
        1000,  5000, 10000,   296,   296,   296,   296,   296,   296,
         296,   255,   588,   319,   444,   468,   432,   600,   480,
         588,   352,   600,   396,   372,   420,  3650,  3645,   248,
        2950,   208,  5000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000,  1000,   500,
         500,   500,   500, 10000,  1000,  5000,  5000,  5000,  5000,
        5000,   500, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000,   600,  2739,
         289,  2753,   277,  4751,  9570,  9601,  6186,  5116,  7996,
        9601,  9613,  8024,  9601,   948,  1440,   600, 10000, 10000,
       10000, 10000, 10000,  5000,  5000,  5000,  5000,  5000,  1534,
        7980,   845,   823,   493,   721,   325,  8280,  5132,  7632,
        2606,  5025,  5190,  7468,  6304,  8760,  9829,  8002,  8393,
        9097,  9470,   678,   676,   658,   658,   655,   643,  2004,
         516,  2288,  1651,  1093,  4111,   695,  1289,  1736,  1656,
        1656,  1656,   452,  4233,   815,  6569,  4613,  2366,  2330,
        1618,  2403,  1346,  1619,   396,  4634,  2847,  5432,  2368,
        2368,  7127,  1527,  1533,  6167,   985,  1836,  1821,  1836,
         629,   747,  5511,  5491,  1656,  2048,  2048,  2048,  2048,
        2048,  2048,  1024,  1024,  1024,  1024,  1024,  2048,  1024,
        1024,  1024,  1024,  4463,  9526,  1000,  9093,  3000,  3000,
        3000,  3000,  3000,  3000,   617,  1548,  2602,  1512,   979,
         549,  2495,  1940,  7601,  2058,  6001,  8808,  8201,  2163,
        2163,  5701,  5901,  3653,  3653,   313,   313,  5101,  6501,
        6601,  7201,  8701,  8901,  9301,  9701,  5401,  6101,  6401,
        7001,  7201,  7401,  7401,  7901,  9901,  9901,  4914,  7842,
        2726,  9201,  7712,  1096,  1100,  6801,   768,  1096,  4655,
        1424,   786,  1687,  5051,  1256,  3549,  8808,   542,   542,
         720,   542,   720,   720,   542,  1506,   825,   894,   825,
        5301,  5701,  5701,  6001,  6601,  6701,  8101,  9101,  1020,
        4560,  3845,  3922,  4491,  3886,  2042,  4106,  1900,  1045,
        2229,  6712,   664,  4317,  3948,  3566,   623,  8420,  3089,
        3362,  1656,  1776,  1656,  1656,  1656,  1550,  1540,  1248,
        1247,  1416,  1540,  1248,  8500,  8800,  7000,  9700,  8500,
        8600,  9800,  8900,  9200, 10000,  2400,  4500,  2200,  1300,
        5800,  1800,  7500,  3700,  3500,  2200,  4000,  1500,  3600,
        6000,  3400,  9000,   259,  1700,  8300,  3800,  4300,  4300,
        1800,  1800,  1800,  1800,  1800,  1800,  1800,  1800,  1800,
        1800,  1800,  1800,  1800,  1800,  6306,  6492,  6264,  6150,
        6276,  6282,  6342,  6102,  6588,  6300,  7104,  6234,  9989,
        9995,  9996,  9993,  9991,  9986,  9994,  9993,  9985,  9986,
        9994,  9999,  9989,  9997,  9991, 10000, 10000,  9700,  7500,
        7900,  9600,  1200,  2100,  1500,  6900,  4900,  3800,  1600,
        2200,  3600,  6000,  5700,  7700,  3200,  1500,  8200,  2800,
        4300,  5400,  1600, 10000,  2600,  5600,  2000,  5500,  8600,
        6300,  4700,  3500,  8600,  3900,  6500,  5300,  6800,  5800,
        3800,  8400,  4600,  1900,  3400,  3000,  5800,  7000,  5900,
        6100]
```

I want to compute spearman's correlation of the dataframes and want to plot them. Plot can be Scatter or heatmap.
But i don't have any idea how it can be done.

Any resource or reference will be helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = [...] # insert here your list of values for A

B = [...] # insert here your list of values for B

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A,
                   'B': B})

corr = df.corr(method = 'spearman')

sns.heatmap(corr, annot = True)

plt.show()
```

I get this correlation matrix:

[image]

The column `A` is highly correlated with itself (obviously, this always happens), while the correlation between column `A` and `B` is very low.

Version info:

```
Python      3.7.0
matplotlib  3.2.1
pandas      1.0.4
seaborn     0.10.1
```

Comment: TypeError: corr() got an unexpected keyword argument 'annot'
getting error is it due to some difference in version ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `jointplot` function from [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) to plot the datapoints. This not only provides you with the scatterplot, but also with the marginal distribution.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": A, "B": B})
sbn.jointplot(x="A", y="B", data=df, alpha=0.2)
```

[image: Plot using jointplot]

To get the spearman's correlation coefficient, you can use the [spearmanr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.spearmanr.html) function from the `scipy` module:

```py
from scipy.stats import spearmanr
r, p = spearmanr(df["A"], df["B"])
# r = 0.008703025102683665
```

Comment: Thanks , really appreciated your efforts